# CheckBoxFor inside a loop -- On client, discover which box changed, and if it was checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a CheckBoxFor inside a loop....

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
{
    ... Some hidden fields ...
    <div>
        <label class="control-label">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Roles[i].Selected, new { @class = "ModelCheckBox" })
            @Model.Roles[i].Name
        </label>
     </div>
}
```

And then this:

```
$('.ModelCheckBox').change(function (e) {
    alert("you changed a role");
});
```

The alert pops up just fine, but what I need to know is what box changed, and if it was checked or unchecked.

In Chrome debug I put a breakpoint so I could look at the contents of `e`, but it doesn't seem to contain any data about which box was checked.

Comment: Can you check the value of "m", instead of "e" (m => Model.Roles...)? Also, check the value of "e.target.value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  In the view, change this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Roles[i].Selected, new { @class = "ModelCheckBox" })
```

to this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Roles[i].Selected, new { @class = "ModelCheckBox", @data_role = Model.Roles[i].Name })
```

And then once we have the data attribute:

```
$('.ModelCheckBox').change(function (e, data) {
    alert($(this).data('role') + " " + e.target.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get which checkbox change simply use `e.target` or `this`.

**Example**

```
$('.ModelCheckBox').change(function (e) {
 var target=this;
 //var target=e.target; // both are same. 
   if ($(target).is(':checked')) {
      alert("checked");
    }else{
    alert("unchecked");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I also needed to know which box changed.